# Call method on form when I click on my UserControl

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls

I created my own button. Not standard, it's a `PictureBox` with two pictures inside. I need to a call method in form which will turn my picture left (the method is complete and this picture is in a `pictureBox` on form). I tried `userControl1.Click`, but nothing happened.

I think it must be an event on `pictureBox` inside my own `UserControl`, but I don't know how to call method which is in my form.

Answer (score 0):

You have to subscribe to the event. Take a look at this doc; http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms366768(v=vs.80).aspx

If you make it so your method to rotate the picture subscribes to the Click event on the picture element then that code will get invoked anytime the picture is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

open the designer, click on your button.  Look over at the properties window, that describes your button.  At the top, there should be a lightning bolt looking icon.  click that, and you can see events for the button.  you need a method in there, that links the button to the event.  To see the code that's involved, open up the designer code and locate your picture box after adding it.

To see if it worked, try adding MessageBox.Show("Test") inside the click function.

---Oops this doesn't apply to you, but may be useful information--

Or, if you want the short way that doesn't explain much, double click your button in the designer  and it should create the Click() event for you.

Comment: I know about events and things, but this is different.. thanks you for comment

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public class YourUserControl : UserControl {
     public YourUserControl(){
        InitializeComponent();            
     }         
     private void pictureBox_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){
        //your code for pictureBox_Click
        OnClick(e);//This is needed if you want to register some Click event handler from ouside your UserControl.
     }
}
```

I think you don't need to use a `UserControl` here, just use a `PictureBox` like this:

```
public class MyButton : PictureBox {
    public MyButton(){

    }
    //
    protected override void OnClick(EventArgs e){
        //Your code here
        //base.OnClick(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks you, but it MUST be UserControl, it's homework and my teacher wants UserControl... but nice idea, thanks you